# PHP 5 type hinting

Tags: php, symfony, types

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

I got this code off of the Symfony2 book.
I am really confused on what the `Request $request` means.

I know the `$request` is a parameter. But I thought PHP doesn't allow declarations? What is the reason? Will only having `newAction($request)` work in the same way? Thanks for helping! :)

Comment: Since php5 you can optionally add typehints to enforce OOP type conformity — from [http://us2.php.net/language.oop5.typehinting](http://us2.php.net/language.oop5.typehinting): "Failing to satisfy the type hint results in a catchable fatal error."

Comment: In short you'll absolutely want to keep the typehint: `newAction(Request $request)` Because you're extending Controller you will want to maintain it's function signatures — consistent interfaces are a core design feature of Symfony2, and it will cause you problems if you start hacking away at them.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! thank you!

Comment: The Symfony Controller Parser system check the input parameter, and if your parameter must be a Request instance, then SF automatically get "request" service from container and set as input parameter. This work only for Request instance.

Comment: I note that the question is tagged [tag:php-5.1]. If you're really still using this version of PHP, you should be looking to upgrade urgently. PHP 5.1 has been unsupported for many years now, and has numerous known security flaws. It is unsafe to still be running software this old on a production system. Plus PHP 5.1 is missing a lot of the features that PHP developers take for granted today; most modern libraries like Symphony require at least 5.3 to work, which means that you must be using obsolete versions of them too, which means even more security flaws and missing features to worry about

Answer (score 0):

That code is absolutely normal. It works even if you drop the type hinting. If you do drop that though you aren't be able to catch a type error anymore (like if you call a method by providing an object of the wrong type).

At the moment PHP 5 supports type hinting only for objects and arrays, so you can do the same with arrays as shown below.

```php
function blah(array $myArray) { //...
```

Type hinting works on the basis of Polymorphism as well, so your method/function will also accept objects that inherit from the specified type.

```php
interface MyInterface {}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {}

function blah(MyInterface $object) {} // this works if you pass an instance of MyClass as well
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

**EDIT**: PHP7 now supports type hinting also for scalar variables: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration